# Oracle 12c OLAP Option enable "on commit" refresh mode

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-olap

I've created a cube using Oracle 12c OLAP option.

I would like to refresh the cube automatically when the data in the underlying tables change.

1. Is it possible without using materialized views?
2. With materialized views, couldn't enable refresh mode - 'on commit'. Has this option been removed in 12c? The following image shows "Refresh Mode" as non-editable.

[image: Cube config showing refresh mode as non-editable]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: Hi Steve, As you could see in the above screen shot the 'Refresh Mode' option is not a drop-down as expected. So I couldn't change it.

Comment: i'd recommend to open a service request with oracle to determine the reason. If you know the materialized view name, you can always change the refresh mode directly, however this might not be recommended as their might be a reason why this option is not offered in the UI.

Comment: Hi, Steve, thank you for the response. Should I have a licence to raise a service request?